# Can I convert List<Date> to ArrayList<String>?

Tags: android, date, arraylist

I have a list of dates stored in `List<Date>` and get the data from method getDates. and now I want to convert it to `ArrayList<String>` but I got this error:

> ArrayList cannot be applied to java.util.List.

because i want to change format of the date from List. And i have tried this one [Convert ArrayList of String type into Date type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33734784/convert-arraylist-of-string-type-into-date-type) 
and to convert date, first date must stored as string but my case my date store in List. the problem is, i still cant to convert List to string.

This is my code:

```
List<Date> dates = getDates(date1, date2);
ArrayList<String> dateStringList = new ArrayList<>();
dateStringList.add(dates);
```

Is there a way to convert data in `List<Date>` to `ArrayList<String>`?
I have tried so many ways but still got error.

Comment: Loop over the list of dates, covert each to a string, then add the string to your dateStringList.  Googling "convert Date to String Java" will give you dozens of answers

Comment: Instantiate your dateStringList as a List instead of an ArrayList

Comment: "Converting" a `Date` to a `String` (this is actually called *formatting*) is a too broad question, because there are many different ways to do it. Ex: today's date can be formatted as `17/08/2017`, `Aug 17th 2017`, `Thu Aug 17 13:19:00 BRT 2017` and so on. You need to know which format you want. Anyway, there are already lots of questions about it in SO, please make a search first, and if you don't find the answer you can **[edit]** the question explaining why the searched questions didn't solve your problem. *I have tried so many ways* - so [edit] the question and add your attempts as well.

Comment: yes there is so many answer about "convert Date to String Java", but it different with my case. i have edited my questions @GabeSechan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use an enhanced for-loop to achieve it, like below:

```
List<Date> dates = getDates(date1, date2);
List<String> dateStringList = new ArrayList<>();

for (Date date : dates) {
    String dateStr = String.valueOf(date);
    dateStringList.add(dateStr);
}
```

In the above code, we actually loop each and every Date in the `dates` list, converting them to String, and adding them to the `dateStringList` list.

And if you need your dateString in a particular format, you should use the method below upon changing to the necessary format:

```
public static String dateToString(Date date) {
    String convertedDate = "";

    try {

        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
        convertedDate = dateFormat.format(date);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("dateToString_EX", e + "");
    }

    return convertedDate;
}
```

And call it like below inside the `for()` loop:

```
for (Date date : dates) {
    //String dateStr = String.valueOf(date);
    String dateStr = dateToString(date);
    dateStringList.add(dateStr);
}
```

Comment: This is actually an accepted answer Mr. DownVoter, why do you down vote unnecessarily?

Answer (score 0):

If you use the jack or JaCoCo ([here](https://developer.android.com/guide/platform/j8-jack.html) more info about it) then you can use lambdas and streams on it!

```
List<Date> myVarList = Arrays.asList(new Date(), new Date(), new Date(), new Date());
List<String> myVarListString = new ArrayList<>();

myVarListString.addAll(myVarList.stream().map(x -> x.toString()).collect(Collectors.toList()));

System.out.println(myVarListString);
System.out.println(myVarList);
```